# We can't hug but we can kiss

Tags: riddle

- Mack always moves in straight lines, turns at right angles.
- Zag moves in a helpless way at first, but can develop later.
- You may have met Mack and Zag aboard the 64.

In a dream, Mack said to Zag: 
*"We can't hug but we can kiss. Please lend me your cat for I haven't taken my pills!"*

**What are the real identities of Mack and Zag?**

Comment: Is the fact that Mack says "borrow me your cat" rather than "lend me your cat" deliberate? (I think some languages don't have separate words for "borrow" and "lend", so if CyberianRat happens to be a native speaker of such a language this would be a natural mistake to make. But perhaps it's a clue.)

Comment: @Gareth, thanks, I wasn't aware of this distinction in English

Comment: Hmm thinking it could be cell phone/tablets charging slot and the USB slot. Pills might be tablets.. Well not sure about 64 though

Comment: 64: Commodore 64? This sounds kinda like they are from a game

Comment: Did you mean "straight" angles (180º), or "right" angles (90º)?

Comment: @Rodrigo: I meant right angles (but straight angles are not excluded)

Comment: Just FYI, that use of "borrow" is common in certain regions of the US.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mack and Zag are, respectively,

> **Pac-Man** from *Pac-Man* and **Wizball** from *Wizball*, both being video game characters.

**Explanation**

- "Mack always moves in straight lines, turns at right angles."

  > Pac-Man moves in straight lines and can only turn at 90-degree angles (or 180-degree angles when he turns back).
  > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pac-Man
  > https://www.c64-wiki.com/index.php/Pac-Man
- "Zag moves in a helpless way at first, but can develop later."

  > Wizball has limited movement at first, but one can acquire enhancements which improve his abilities.
  > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizball
  > https://www.c64-wiki.com/index.php/Wizball
  > (Thanks to kayzeroshort for indicating the game).
- "You may have met Mack and Zag aboard the 64."

  > "The 64" stands for the Commodore 64. Both *Pac-Man* and *Wizball* have versions for that computer.
  > (Thanks to Areeb for pointing this out)

The dream:

*"We can't hug but we can kiss."*

> **Neither Pac-Man nor Wizball have arms (they can't hug), but they both have mouths (they can kiss)**.

*"Please lend me your cat for I haven't taken my pills!"*

> **The cat is Wizball's companion, Catellite,** which helps him in the game.
> **The pills refer to Pac-Man's power pills**, which allow him to eat the ghosts that chase him.

Comment: This should be the answer. +1 And for C64 you can add this [link](https://www.c64-wiki.com/index.php/Pac-Man)

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizball

Comment: Marked as correct. Even without knowing Zag's identity, Rodrigo solved all the key parts of the puzzle, congratulations! Kayzeroshot's comment completes it.

Comment: @CyberianRat Wow, that's nice. :) I'll edit the answer later today, when I have a little more time, in order to update it with kayzeroshort's contribution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I have

> Mack and Zag are chess pieces.
> Mack is the rook.
>  Zag is probably the pawn(Thanks,Gareth)
>  And the kiss probably means en passant of the pawn which is French.(Saiid from the Sphinx Lair)
>  The dream part is where my theory fails
>  (Note)- [Gareth McCaughan mentioned this in the Sphinx Lair chat but I had independently come up with this as well.]

Comment: `*cough*` where did you get the kiss part from?

Comment: Oh, dear, I forgot... Added your contribution

Comment: A chess board has 64 squares?

Comment: @Areeb yes, they are 8x8.

Comment: @Saiid I meant that as a solution to the third bullet point

Comment: @Areeb Oh. that *is* where he got the chess stuff from...

Comment: @Saiid yeah I realize that now, I read the chat in the mean time

Comment: Its a dream. And hence donesn't need a mouth to kiss. :D +1

Comment: @Techidiot you don't need a mouth to kiss anyway [.-.](https://www.google.com/search?q=eskimo+kiss)

Comment: Why did you eliminate the possibility that Mack could be the bishop?

Comment: @Massaraksh "Mack always moves in straight lines, ***turns at right angles***"

Comment: Sorry, chess was a red herring